How to echo out a line ending in a "=0" into a file
Using the batch file generator.bat:
REM Test file creator
SETLOCAL

ECHO Test generated file! >>testfile.txt
ECHO assign var1=0>>testfile.txt
ECHO assign var1=1>>testfile.txt
ECHO assign var1=two>>testfile.txt
ECHO assigned var1>>testfile.txt

ENDLOCAL

I am able to generate the file: testfile.txt
Test generated file! 
assign var1=
assign var1=two
assigned var1

How can I add some sort of separator character so these lines are printed properly? The intended output file testfile.txt would be:
Test generated file! 
assign var1=0
assign var1=1
assign var1=two
assigned var1

Adding a space before the >> ie:
ECHO assign var1=0 >>testfile.txt

Simply results in the following:
assign var1=0 

Where the value is actually 0  (space added). This is an issue because I am using a similar generator to create another batch file, and the additional whitespace changes the meaning of the value.

Added spaces which changed the output values to have spaces appended
Tried to put the line into a variable and echo out the variable


In addition to the methods in the existing answer, individually you could do it like these examples: (Echo assign var1=0) 1>>"testfile.txt", (Echo assign var1=1) 1>>"testfile.txt".

You've got two options:
you can either move the redirection to the front of the line
>>testfile.txt ECHO assign var1=0
>>testfile.txt ECHO assign var1=1

or you can put everything in parentheses since you have multiple redirects going to the same file
(
    ECHO Test generated file!
    ECHO assign var1=0
    ECHO assign var1=1
    ECHO assign var1=two
    ECHO assigned var1
)>>testfile.txt


If that the start of the file, or its complete content then you can use > instead of >> in the second example. Although technically it should be 1>. Also as you are strangely exclaiming the first line, you should ensure that delayed expansion is not enabled.
